# How to check the table whether the same roll number exists or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

1. Can we can check the roll number already exists or not.

   with javascript
2. can we validate this
3. Showing with a alert message that the roll number exists if it is
   already in the table

.

```js
window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById('new').style.display = 'none';
     };
     function addtable(){
    document.getElementById('new').style.display = 'block';
       Rollno = document.getElementById("roll_number");
       Name = document.getElementById("student_name");
       Class = document.getElementById("class");
       var Gender = null;
         var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('gender');
         for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
             if(inputElements[i].checked){
              Gender = inputElements[i].value;
              break;
            }
         };
         Age = document.getElementById("age");
         Phone = document.getElementById("phone_number");
         var Result = null; 
      var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
      for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
        if(inputElements[i].checked){
            Result = inputElements[i].value;
            break;
        }
      };
    var table = document.getElementById("new");
    rowCount = table.rows.length;
    row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= Rollno.value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= Name.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= Class.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= Gender;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= Age.value;
    row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= Phone.value;
    row.insertCell(6).innerHTML= Result;
    row.insertCell(7).innerHTML='<input type="submit" value = "Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';

   
    var roll = document.forms["student_detail"]["roll_number"].value;
    if (roll == "") {
        alert("Rollno must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var name = document.forms["student_detail"]["student_name"].value;
    if (name == ""){
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var clas = document.forms["student_detail"]["class"].value;
    if (clas == "") {
        alert("select the class");
        return false;
    }
    var age = document.forms["student_detail"]["age"].value;
    if (age == ""){
        alert("Age must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var phone = document.forms["student_detail"]["phone_number"].value;
    if (phone == "") {
        alert("Phone number must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.student_detail.result1.checked == true && document.student_detail.result2.checked == true){
        alert('Select any one result');
        return false ;
     }

    }

    function deleteRow(obj) {
      
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("new");
    table.deleteRow(index);
    
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById('myTable');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
      var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
      if (change.innerHTML === "Hide Form")
      {
        change.innerHTML = "Show Form";
      }
      else {
        change.innerHTML = "Hide Form";
      }
    }
    function hideElem(){
    document.getElementById('new').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    function showElem(){
    document.getElementById('new').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

```css
.abc table{
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .abc table th{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .abc table td{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    h2{
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000
    }    
    input[type=text],select,input[type=number]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=button] {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
    }

    div {
     border-radius: 5px;
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
     padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
 
     
    
    <form name="student_detail" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return addtable();">
    <table id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <td><h2>School Management Application</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="roll_number">Roll no</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="roll_number" name="roll_number" placeholder="Roll Number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="student_name">Student name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="student_name" name="student_name" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="class">Class</label></td>
            <td><select name="class" id="class">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Gender</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
            <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="age">Age</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="phone_number">Phone number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Result</label></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="result" name="result1" value="passed" >Passed
            <input type="checkbox" class="result" name="result2" value="failed" />Failed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addtable()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
     <table>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Hide Form" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()">
            <input type="button" value="Hide table" id="tab" onclick="hideElem()">
            <input type="button" value="Show table" id="tab1" onclick="showElem()"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>

    <div class="abc">
     <table id="new">
          <tr>
          <th>Rollno</th>
       <th>Student name</th>
       <th>Class</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Phone number</th> 
       <th>Result</th>
       </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

- Need to get alert if the same roll number enters again.After
  submiting  And a alert message to be shown

  Can any one help me to do this

Comment: Very poorly asked question. Instead of dumping all your code here, please [create a complete and minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but you should probably be able to answer the *"can we validate this"* yourself. We would rather see your attempt (note what @ankitbug94 said) with a specific question on the issue you're running into - if any at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that checks for duplicates

```
checkDupes($("#someId"));


function checkDupes(itemArray) {
            var isdupe = false;
            for (var i = itemArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var value = itemArray[i].value;
                if (value == null || value == '' || value.trim().length == 0) {
                    itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                } else {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        for (var j = i - 1; j > -1 && i > 0; j--) {
                            if (value.trim().toLowerCase() == itemArray[j].value.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                                itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                                isdupe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isdupe) {
                            itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why will anyone use such a long code for checking duplicates

Comment: It just not check for duplicates, I wrote it to do validation and add some styling to indicate errors.